# How to resolve or stop EIGRP continuous log message Issues

Tags: eigrp

How do I stop this continuous log message because I cannot make any amendments on the router in cisco packet tracer?

this is how it looks like:

```
eq 1/0 idbQ 0/0 iidbQ un/rely 0/0

EIGRP: Received HELLO on GigabitEthernet0/2 nbr 192.168.10.1
  AS 555, Flags 0x0, Seq 1/0 idbQ 0/0

EIGRP: recv packet with wrong subnet on GigabitEthernet0/2

EIGRP: Received HELLO on GigabitEthernet0/2 nbr 192.168.1.1
  AS 555, Flags 0x0, Seq 5/0 idbQ 0/0

EIGRP: recv packet with wrong subnet on GigabitEthernet0/2

EIGRP: Sending HELLO on GigabitEthernet0/2
  AS 555, Flags 0x0, Seq 1/0 idbQ 0/0 iidbQ un/rely 0/0
```

Comment: It would help to provide the message, and the map & configs.

Comment: this is how it looks like:
eq 1/0 idbQ 0/0 iidbQ un/rely 0/0

EIGRP: Received HELLO on GigabitEthernet0/2 nbr 192.168.10.1
  AS 555, Flags 0x0, Seq 1/0 idbQ 0/0

EIGRP: recv packet with wrong subnet on GigabitEthernet0/2

EIGRP: Received HELLO on GigabitEthernet0/2 nbr 192.168.1.1
  AS 555, Flags 0x0, Seq 5/0 idbQ 0/0

EIGRP: recv packet with wrong subnet on GigabitEthernet0/2

EIGRP: Sending HELLO on GigabitEthernet0/2
  AS 555, Flags 0x0, Seq 1/0 idbQ 0/0 iidbQ un/rely 0/0

Answer (score 2):

If you enabled that with `terminal monitor`, you could use `terminal no monitor`.

If this is a result of using `debug`, the you can use `undebug all`.